# SQL query on a condition

Tags: sql, foreign-keys

I'm writing a query to retrieve translated content. I want it so that if there isn't a translation for the given language id, it automatically returns the translation for the default language, with Id 1.

```
select Translation.Title
      ,Translation.Summary
from Translation
where Translation.FkLanguageId = 3

-- If there is no LanguageId of 3, select the record with LanguageId of 1.
```

I'm working in MS SQL but I think the theory is not DBMS-specific.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm working in MS SQL but didn't think it made much difference as its just the logic I'd like help with

Comment: How are "the same" translations grouped?

Comment: Surely this table is a collection of phrases so there must be a phraseID or something like that.  What does the table structure look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This assumes *one* row per Translation only, based on how you phrased the question. If you have multiple rows per FkLanguageId and I've misunderstood, please let us know and the query becomes more complex of course

```
select TOP 1
   Translation.Title
   ,Translation.Summary
from
    Translation
where
    Translation.FkLanguageId IN (1, 3)
ORDER BY
    FkLanguageId DESC
```

You'd use LIMIT in another RDBMS

Comment: Nice answer, please could you explain how this would be integrated into a more complicated query, such as this: http://pastie.org/1359177

Comment: @Greg: See Martin's answer which allows for multiple rows per ID.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the table contains different phrases grouped by `PhraseId`

```
WITH Trans As
(
select Translation.Title
      ,Translation.Summary
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PhraseId ORDER BY FkLanguageId DESC) RN
from Translation
where Translation.FkLanguageId IN (1,3)
)
SELECT *
FROM Trans WHERE RN=1
```

Answer (score 1):

This assumes the existance of a TranslationKey that associates one "topic" with several different translation languages:

```
SELECT
  isnull(tX.Title, t1.Title)      Title
 ,isnull(tX.Summary, t1.Summary)  Summary
from Translation t1
 left outer join Translation tX
  on tx.TranslationKey = t1.Translationkey
   and tx.FkLanguageId = @TargetLanguageId
where t1.FkLanguageId = 1  --  "Default
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is a dirty solution, but it can help you

```
if not exists(select t.Title ,t.Summary from Translation t where t.FkLanguageId = 3)
    select t.Title ,t.Summary from Translation t where t.FkLanguageId = 1
else
    select t.Title ,t.Summary from Translation t where t.FkLanguageId = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your reference to pastie.org shows that you're looking up phrases or specific menu item names in a table I'm going to assume that there is a phrase ID to identify the phrases in question.

```
SELECT  ISNULL(forn_lang.Title, default_lang.Title) Title,
        ISNULL(forn_lang.Summary, default_lang.Summary) Summary
FROM    Translation default_lang
LEFT OUTER JOIN Translation forn_lang ON default_lang.PhraseID = forn_lang.PhraseID AND forn_lang.FkLanguageId = 3
WHERE   default_lang.FkLanguageId = 1
```

Comment: You'd need to move the "= 3" condition to the JOIN: this is an INNER JOIN as it stands

Comment: Right you are! Didn't think that through properly.